# Image preview before selecting

Tags: android

I am currently able to select an image from the gallery and return its filepath back to my app on android, however I want to know if it was possible to preview the image first before selecting it?  If so how would one achieve this?  Thanks

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        //startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

and here is my onResult method

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        old_User = username; //needed if after selecting image you wish to change user

        if(old_User != null){
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);          
            dataBank.put(old_User, selectedImagePath);
            KeyColumn.add(old_User);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            EditText userText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_box);
            userText.setText("");
        } 
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "FAILED TO GET FILEPATH...", duration).show();
    }
}
```

This piece of code gets me to the gallery but when I select a picture it doesn't open up the picture as a preview instead it goes straight back to the app and gets the file path of the image. So I can't see the full size image before actually selecting it, instead I just see part of the image sort of like an icon view of it.

Comment: Isn't the gallery **itself** a preview?

Comment: @DerGolem I have edited my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use startActivityForResult to open Gallery app and select one of them.

in OnResult method, if the first request (Gallery) is OK then start and another activity for result which is displays image and asks again like Do you want to continue or something else and then again in OnResult method, if request is from your activty and result was OK you can keep doing whatever you want.

Good luck.